# Running VBA Macro in AutoCAD

Tags: vba, autocad, autolisp

I'm making a .bundle folder for the plugins I've programmed for AutoCAD. At the root of the folder is my PackageContents.xml bundle where all of my Lisp plugins are autoloaded. Since .dvb is not a supported type for Autoloading I made a Lisp file to be autoloaded with the following code

```
(defun C:CSC ()
  (vl-vbaload "WindowsDoors.dvb")
  (vl-vbarun "WindowsDoors.dvb!CAD_STANDARD_CREATOR!CAD_STANDARD_BLOCK!CAD_STANDARD_PATH")
)
```

The code runs and puts my plugin, WindowsDoors.dvb into AutoCAD but when I try to use the plugin the command line gives me the following

```
Command -vbarun
Initializing VBA System
Macro name: RunMeWindowDoor   Execution error
```

Normally this would suggest a bug in the code except when I manually load this plugin with AutoCAD 2014's built in application loader under the manage tab it works fine leaving me with no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to change the code to this

```
(defun C:LoadDVB ()
  (command "vbaload" "WindowsDoors.dvb")
)
```

Comment: Hi nick, don't forget to accept this answer, you'll get a little rep and it'll be useful to other people. Glad you got it sorted out!